# Eclipse SSC Plugin Fails SSC Upload

Tags: eclipse, plugins, timezone

I have an interesting situation that would like to know if there is a working solution.  Our developers are on Network A running the eclipse plugin.  The SSC server (4.21) is on Network B.  Network A is configured with EST timezone while Network B is configured with UTC (5 hour difference).  When the developer attempts to upload scan results through the plugin, the SSC server rejects the upload due to the time difference (it sees the code as in the future).

Is there a way around this?  Network B is set to UTC to mirror the customers environment so it can't be readily changed.  Likewise, Network A is not allowed to host the SSC server due to contractual reasons.

Looking for any insight or potential workarounds.